Compare 2 dataframes to find a missing row
I imported a dataframe containing 25098 rows. Upon checking the data once it was imported I discovered that one row was missing as the imported data had only 25097 rows. Since I have a backup of the original data, I would like to check it against the imported data to determine which row is missing
How can I find the specific missing row, hopefully using Pandas or a similar Python library? I am still a newbie, hoping to use any answers as part of my learning experience. Thanks

What is the input format? How do you know the original data has 25098 rows? Did you include the header? Also note that rows of data are not the sames are lines in a CSV (one row can span several lines)

That said, you can compare two DataFrames by doing an anti-merge: see here

It would help providing the exact commands you used to create/load the original data, then export it. Currently, we can only speculate

Thank you very much, sir. Your link contained just the exact solution I was looking for. I used the second option from Polly's answer to resolve my issue. Much indebted
